# Pass React component as prop to another component which itself require prop in dependent

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have three component that call each other in a cascade:

> ----Priority
> --------Base
> ------------ItemDialog

##### First component (Priority) needs a parameter (item) from third component (ItemDialog)

---

**Priority** component is:

```
export Priority = () => {
  const itemDialogFields = (item) => {
    return (
      <ItemDialogFields item={item} />
    )
  }

  return (
    <Base itemDialogFields={itemDialogFields} />
  )
}
```

**Base** component code:

```
export Base = ({itemDialogFields}) => {
  return (
      <ItemDialog itemDialogFields={itemDialogFields} />
  )
}
```

And **ItemDialog** component:

```
export ItemDialog = ({itemDialogFields}) => {
  return (
    {itemDialogFields(item)}
  )
}
```

I want to remove `itemDialogFields` **function** from `Priority` component and pass `ItemDialogFields` **component** directly to `Base` component as:

```
export Priority = () => {
return (
    <Base itemDialogFields={<ItemDialogFields item={item} />} />
  )
}
```

But it need `item` prop. Currently I get `item` as a **function parameter** and pass it as a `props` to `ItemDialogFields` component, but if I change code as I said **how can I pass `item` to this component?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used HOC to figure this out and I think I found the solution.

**Priority**

```
export Priority = () => {

return Base(ItemDialogFields, "item")
```

**Base**

```
// This function takes a component and any other argument...
export default function Base(ItemDialogFields, item) {
  // ... and renders the ItemDialogFields component
  // Notice that we pass through any additional props
  return <ItemDialogFields item={item} />;
}
```

**ItemDialogFields**

```
const ItemDialogFields= ({ item }) => {
  return item;
};

export default ItemDialogFields;
```

Source: ([https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#:~:text=A%20higher%2Dorder%20component%20(HOC,and%20returns%20a%20new%20component.)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#:%7E:text=A%20higher%2Dorder%20component%20(HOC,and%20returns%20a%20new%20component.))

I hope it will help you with the problem

Good day!